# Thymeleaf print entity attribute on html without span tag

Tags: thymeleaf

I need some custom css in html page which css styling is retrieve from database. When page invoke controller will render css style to html. I want to display the color code only instead of whole span tags.

This is result I need:

```
color: #159426;
```

This is unexpected result I get:

```
color: <span>#159426</span>;
```

**This is my directory structure.**

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" name="viewport"/>
  <style th:include="generic/templates/init :: init" th:with="params=${params}"/>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
  <a><h1>....111</h1></a>
  <h1>....222</h1>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**This is init.html**

```
<script th:inline="javascript" th:fragment="init">
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .site-title {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }

    body.site {
        border-top: 3px solid <span th:text="${params.templateColor}"/>;
        background-color: <span th:text="${params.templateBackgroundColor}"/>;
    }

    a {
        color: <span th:text="${params.templateColor}"/>;
    }
</script>
```

**This is my result**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" name="viewport" />
  <style>
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .site-title {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    
    body.site {
      border-top: 3px solid <span>#159426</span>;
      background-color: <span>#f4f6f7</span>;
    }
    
    a {
      color: <span>#159426</span>;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
  <a><h1>....111</h1></a>
  <h1>....222</h1>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using the

```
th:remove="tag"
```

for example substitute

```
a {
        color: <span th:text="${params.templateColor}" />;
  }
```

with this one

```
a {
        color: <span th:text="${params.templateColor}" th:remove="tag"/>;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using html tags in your css, you should really be using [inlining](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining).  Thymeleaf 3 suports this out of the box.  Your style tags should look like this:

```
<style th:fragment="init">
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .site-title {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }

    body.site {
        border-top: 3px solid [[${params.templateColor}]];
        background-color: [[${params.templateBackgroundColor}]];
    }

    a {
        color: [[${params.templateColor}]];
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Metroids, it's not working for me. I using spring boot with basic thymeleaf dependency org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf

Comment: If you're using thymeleaf 2, you might have to change the style tag to look like this: `<style th:fragment="init" th:inline="text">`